# How do iI call textArea from main class so that I can use it in another class?

Tags: java, jtextarea

I want to do like if I clicked on btn_check, error message will appear on txt_msg (JTExtArea). I've done this code using command-line, it works. It's just I want to apply it in my GUI.

This is my Main class

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object click = e.getSource();

    if (click == btn_check){
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String line;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txt_file.getText()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            } // end while in try

            String everything = sb.toString();

        } catch (IOException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } //end try - catch - finally

        File filename = new File(txt_area.getText());

        try {
            txt_msg.setText("Yes in Main");
            // Scan file - read tokens
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new UnicodeEscapes(new FileReader(filename)));      

            //  Parse the file
            parser parser = new parser(scanner);
            parser.parse();

            parser p = new parser(txt_msg); //this is where I want to pass my text area to parser class

        } catch (Exception err) {
            syntax_err = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my parser class

```
JTextArea new_txt_msg;

public parser(JTextArea a) {
    new_txt_msg = a;
}

public void report_error(String message, Object info) {
StringBuffer m = new StringBuffer("Error ");

if (info instanceof java_cup.runtime.Symbol) 
  m.append( "("+info.toString()+")" );

m.append(" : "+message);

System.out.println(m); //m holds the error message
}
```

I've tried to use `new_txt_msg.setText(m.toString())` but it didn't work.

Comment: I would guess it would be as simple as `mainclass.JTextArea.getText()` but if not you would need a `setter` and a `getter`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the code you provided, but from what I see here you're creating a new parser object, on which you didn't call the parse() method like you did on the one before. If that's the problem you will need to:

- create a new constructor for your parser class, which gets both the Scanner and the JTextArea
- call the parse() method on it
- have the parse() method call your report_error() method
- now in your parse() method you will be able to call the setText()

what I suggest though, if you can, is to make your parse() method to return the error message (or a more complex object holding the message and some kind of return code), and make the call to the setText() method on the JTextArea directly inside the actionPerformed(). In this way you will decouple the pure computation (input parsing) and the GUI management (dislpay the computation result).

Also, have a look to the [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class; if your parsing can be a long operation, calling it from the actionPerformed() method could hang your GUI

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've asked a senior in my faculty, he said that too. But i cant change the data type of method `report_error()` because it's kind of default in class parser (`parser extends java_cup.runtime.lr_parser`). So, I'm trying to pass the value m to other method (I cretaed a new method `write()`), which can return the value of m. My problem now is I don't know how to call the method in Main. Would you help me? :)

Comment: I don't think you need another method to return m, you already have report_error() - just make it return m.toString().


As for the subclassing problem, I need more information... did you override the parse() method or are you using the superclass implementation? How do you use the report_error() method?

Comment: I see, sorry I don't know the library... so we have to get back to the previous solution: when you define the subclass of parser give it a constructor like this: public myParser(Scanner in, JTextArea a) { super(in); new_txt_msg = a;} and then call new_txt_msg.setText(m.toString()) as you wanted to do in the first place

Comment: still not working :( it's okay, I'll tell my lecturer tomorrow. Thanks btw :)

Comment: well I can't go any further without the full code... good luck! :)